# alert after stochastic RSI <=20 and green candle appears after many bars

Tags: pine-script

I want to make an alert in pine script that can keep something that happened and only if it happened it waits for something else to happen and then make an alert. for example I want alert if stochastic rsi was <20 and now stochastic rsi is <50 and there is a green candle. but I dont want an alert when stochastic rsi was >80 and "now stochastic rsi is <50 and there is a green candle" how can i do it? I tried with if condition like:

```
 temp=false
if ( stochastic rsi <=20) 
        then temp=true 
if temp==true and stochastic rsi is <50 and there is a green candle
     then alert
```

but it is not working it feels like I can test only what happens right now.. I can check the close price of old candles I guess but, I don't find it helpful or easy to calculate.. there has to be an easier way .. how can I keep the history for checking?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
alertcondition(Any condition, title='Your Alert')
```

Comment: I used this alert function but how can I check in the "any condition" field that the price was lately in rsi <20 (if now rsi is <20 and there is a red candle i dont want alert but when after that cames green candle i want alert even if rsi is greater than 20 it is importent that rsi was <20 before